# appendTo $(this) statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time trying to append the next image to the `.thumbwrap`, what's the best way to `appendTo` $(this)

```
$('.thumbwrap').each(function (index, el) {
    $(this).find('img:gt(0)').hide();
    $(this).hover(function () {
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                $(this).find(':first-child').fadeOut(0)
                    .next('img')
                    .fadeIn(0)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo(el);
            }, 1000);
        }, function () {
            clearInterval(timer);
        },
        function () {

        });
});
```

Comment: And if you had the correct context for `this`, wouldn't `this` actually be `.thumbwrap`, and yet you're doing `$(this).find('.thumbwrap')` ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes you correct, but it didn't seem to be working. So I thought you had to 'find' it

Comment: Also note that you already have a reference to the element in the variable `el` !

Comment: It would be better if you show the HTML structure too

Comment: try `var self=this;` and replace all `this` in above JS with `self` so that `self` refers `thumbwrap`

Comment: @uriah, Sorry, I didn't get your exact problem? Can I have your html view also?